# What are the Watson Assistant IP Ranges?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

We are using AWS for our infrastructure needs and IBM Cloud is only used for its IBM Watson service for NLP/NLU.

I have asked this question to IBM Watson support, however, I couldn't get an answer. The internet doesn't seem to have a clear answer to it either.

I was wondering when setting up my webhook to a lambda function on AWS, in order to make it more secure, which IP addresses should I allow in order to make it public only to IBM Watson webhooks?

Comment: And you use Watson Assistant in what region? And you probably saw this: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-faqs#faqs-webhook-ip What do you expect from your question?

Comment: @data_henrik I was expecting your comment. I didn't know Watson had that in its FAQs that this is not possible to share. So, I can use their preferred method instead. You can answer the question with your link and I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IP ranges for Watson Assistant are not available due to deployment flexability. [It is covered in the FAQ](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-faqs#faqs-webhook-ip).